# Duplicate Classes to handle app flow (with explicit intents)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation

I have three different options in my app that allow the user through several of the same classes but at different times, ie

1) Sharing with friend:

*MainClass -> InviteFriendOrGroup -> Sharing -> IM*

2) Creating event with friends

*MainClass -> InviteFriendOrGroup -> CreateEvent -> OpenEventsPage*

3) Creating event with no friends:

*MainClass -> CreateEvent -> OpenEventsPage*

My issue is with the intents to allow for this navigation without so many duplicate classes. For example, in the InviteFriendOrGroup class, `onListItemClick` method

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SpecialSharing.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

which means that only open 1) above is allowed. An easy solution is to make duplicate classes, but with the different intents in them, ie.InviteFriendOrGroupEvent, or InviteFriendOrGroupSharing....

But there has to be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't duplicate the classes. Pass parameters using "extras" in the `Intent` to control which options are available.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: First give me a concrete example where you think you need duplicate classes and why. Then I can give you a better way to do it. Your examples aren't really detailed enough to understand why you think you need duplicate classes.

Comment: I think I understand where you are coming from. I should be building multiple intents within the same class and executed given where it's coming from, ie. `String fromWhere = intent.putExtra("fromSharingButton", "fromSharingButton")` then can create an if statement in the onClick to direct it to the correct activity as, `if(fromWhere == fromSharingButton) then navigate to sahring, else creating event class`....correct?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't know your entire application architecture, but I think you are getting the point. If you have multiple entry points to an `Activity`, then you can use information in "extras" to tell the Activity how you got there, so it can decide what to show or where to direct the user next.

Comment: I was thinking, is what I am doing considered good design? ie. MainClass -> InviteFriendOrGroup -> CreateEvent -> OpenEventsPage, this kind of seems like allot of steps. What do you think?